Need help about Boltztrap 2
Recently I am calculating thermoelectric properties of a ABX3 perovsktes using Boltztrap2. But I can not understand here how Can I choose the correct k points for scf and nscf calculations. I have use $8\times 8\times 8$ for scf and $14\times 14\times 14$ for nscf, but I have found some unwanted value as PF exceed 1. Can have idea about it?

Welcome! This is a good question. I think it will be a little easier for folks to answer if you unpack (spell out) the acronyms :)

Does PF mean Power Factor? How did you define this? And about choosing the k-mesh dimensions, you need to provide the size of your supercell and possibly the structure too (an scf or nscf input file would suffice).

The title is also not specific enough.
